# Asking database for a list of usernames

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to print my usernames Into a list on my page. I've wrote my query correct im sure of that but i get this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_users() (previously declared in C:\wamp1\www\cms1\user_list.php:70) in C:\wamp1\www\cms1\includes\user_list_functions.php on line 7

Here is the part of the user_list.php:70

```
function get_users($username){
    echo $username;
}
```

here is my function : User_list_functions.php:7

```
function get_users($username) { 
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users_survey WHERE username = {$username} ORDER BY position ASC";
    $username = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($username);
}
```

Comment: And what is the point of redeclaring?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is clear, you have two `get_users` functions

Comment: I physically lol'd when i read the question.

Comment: Me too ! =D sometimes, reading error messages can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have included `user_list.php` in `User_list_functions.php` and   that's why both functions are conflicting...

Sol: either remove the included `user_list.php` or use classes (object oriented programming) for a better understanding or result...